# What would be the OOP way to solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to solve this problem.

> There is a robot starting at position (0, 0), the origin, on a 2D plane. Given a  sequence of its moves, judge if this robot ends up at (0, 0) after it completes its  moves.
>
> The move sequence is represented by a string, and the character moves[i] represents its ith move. Valid moves are R (right), L (left), U (up), and D (down). If the robot returns to the origin after it finishes all of its moves, return true. Otherwise, return false.
>
> Note: The way that the robot is "facing" is irrelevant. "R" will always make the robot move to the right once, "L" will always make it move left, etc. Also, assume that the magnitude of the robot's movement is the same for each move.
>
> Example 1:
>
> - Input: moves = "UD"
> - Output: true
> - Explanation: The robot moves up once, and then down once. All moves have the same magnitude, so it ended up at the origin where it started. Therefore, we return true.
>
> Example 2:
>
> - Input: moves = "LL"
> - Output: false
> - Explanation: The robot moves left twice. It ends up two "moves" to the left of the origin. We return false because it is not at the origin at the end of its moves.
>
> Example 3:
>
> - Input: moves = "RRDD"
> - Output: false
>
> Example 4:
>
> - Input: moves = "LDRRLRUULR"
> - Output: false

Even though I solved it using counters as well as conditionals, I would like to see how I could use Python's OOP components to solve this. How can I separate out the valid moves, which are R (right), L (left), U (up), and D (down) into separate methods for better abstraction, so that I could add more methods in future? How would the refactored code look like? This is the solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def judgeCircle(self, moves):
        x = y = 0
        for move in moves:
            if move == 'U': y -= 1
            elif move == 'D': y += 1
            elif move == 'L': x -= 1
            elif move == 'R': x += 1

        return x == y == 0
```

Comment: And also, you've forgotten `self` everywhere. So `x` and `y` are always 0 at the start of the function. No `__init__` either.

Comment: I think this questions is a bit too small to fully use OOP. Instead I would advice to take a look at the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections) module. The reason for this is that you can use `collections.Counter(moves)`, to get a count of every occurring character, in a dictionary. Then you can check if the count of left to right and up to down are equal.

Comment: @aneroid, at Leetcode the Solution class is already provided like this for you, so there is no need for `__init__` and `self` arguments (yet). I do agree that the OP could take a look at [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) to see how to implement one from scratch. Then this provided method (`judgeCircle`) is already OOP based, since it does only one thing, namely checking if it walked in a circle.

Comment: @Thymen Ah, got it, thanks! Just checked the link from the previous edit. That one function is provided all the moves at one go and then it just needs to return True/False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it by [encapsulating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) the data and the code that acts on it — both key OOP features. Note though that using "getters" and "setters" is not "pythonic" (because they are generally unnecessary and can be added retroactively if the need ever arises for some reason).

```
class Solution:

    class Mover:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x, self.y = x, y
        def new_pos(self, x, y):
            return x + self.x, y + self.y

    WALKS = dict(U=Mover(0, -1), D=Mover(0, 1),
                 L=Mover(-1, 0), R=Mover(1, 0))

    def judge_circle(self, moves):
        x = y = 0
        for id in moves:
            x, y = self.WALKS[id].new_pos(x, y)

        return x == y == 0


solution = Solution()
sequences = "UD", "LL", "RRDD", "LDRRLRUULR"

for moves in sequences:
    print(solution.judge_circle(moves))
```